# Random numbers in MATLAB, what is this code doing

Tags: matlab, random

I have come across this code,

Essentially I need to generate two vectors of random numbers,

Here is the code,

```
T = 500
     e = normrnd(0,1,[2*T,k]);

        T = size(e,1);
        e = [e(ceil(rand(T,1)*T),:);e];
```

Why is this method used with ceil? Any ideas on why someone would use this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Matlab indexing starts from `1`, `ceil()` will transform `0.8 to 1`
- Matlab index can only take integer values `ceil()` always returns an integer

```
   >> x = rand(3,1)*5

    x =

        4.3117
        4.4820
        0.9451

    >> ceil(x)

    ans =

         5
         5
         1
```

---

```
ceil(rand(m,n)*imax) and randi([1, imax], [m, n]) are equivalent.
```

To confirm the preference for using `ceil()`, one should have a look on those methods documentation, by typing `open ceil` on the command window for example

- `rand()`

```
Copyright 1984-2017 The MathWorks, Inc.
```

- `ceil()`

```
Copyright 1984-2005 The MathWorks, Inc.
```

- `randi()`

```
Copyright 2008-2013 The MathWorks, Inc.
```

In earlier Matlab version `1984~2008a`, `randi()` wasn't available.

The only alternative was using `rand() and ceil() or rand() and floor()` to generate uniformly distributed random integers.

> In short, using `ceil() and rand()` you can generate random number on
>   **all Matlab versions** while `randi()` works only on versions **later than 2008b version.**

Comment: yes but why would you use that method for generating random numbers

Comment: @FrancisOrigi: Good question. That code should have used `randi` instead. I guess the programmer is not aware of that function and tried to roll his own.

Comment: There are two versions of MATLAB released every year. You can look at the documentation to learn in which version a function was introduced, it is shown at the bottom of every documentation page, just below the "see also" section. [`randi` was introduced in R2008b](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html#buf2csg_seealso).

Comment: @FrancisOrigi if my answer satisfies you please accept it.

Comment: @Adam while it explains ceil, I could have easily searched for this, I am more interested in the method, why would they use this, whats the difference between just a random numbers

Comment: @FrancisOrigi  technically there is no difference, just an alternative when `randi` wasn't available, but yes we can wait for new responses